# $M'\bigoplus M''\overset{\phi}\cong M\implies\phi(M'\bigoplus0)=M'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $M$ an $R$-module, $M',M''$ submodules of $M$, $M'\bigoplus M''=\{(m',m'':m'\in M', m''\in M''\}$, the direct sum of $M',M''$. If $M'\bigoplus M''\overset{\phi}\cong M$, then $\phi(M'\bigoplus0)\cong M'$

$\phi(M'\bigoplus0)$ is indeed $M'$, that is, $\phi(M'\bigoplus0)=M'$ as sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup!

$\phi \restriction M' \oplus 0$ is still an injection, so $\phi \restriction M' \oplus 0$ is a bijection from $M' \oplus 0$ to $\phi[M' \oplus 0]$ (By restricting the codomain, we *make* $\phi$ surjective, and thus bijective). But $M' \oplus 0 \cong M'$, and so

$$ M' \cong M' \oplus 0 \cong \phi(M' \oplus 0) $$

As desired.

---

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But I am wondering if $\phi(M'\bigoplus0)$ is the same as $M'$ as sets. I just added one more sentence in my question.

Comment: They don't have to be the same as sets! As an example, take $\mathbb{Z}_{\text{red}} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{\text{blue}}$ where $\mathbb{Z}_{\text{red}} = \{(z,\text{red})~|~z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{\text{blue}} = \{(z,\text{blue})~|~z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_\text{red} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_\text{blue} \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ in the obvious way (forget about $\text{red}$ and $\text{blue}$), but restricting the isomorphism gives $\mathbb{Z}_\text{red} \cong \mathbb{Z}$, which are different as sets

Comment: $\phi(M'\bigoplus0)$ is a submodule of $M$ which is isomorphic to $M'$. Is $\phi(M'\bigoplus0)$ indeed the submodule $M'$?

Comment: Still no, unfortunately. Consider $\mathbb{z}_\text{red} \oplus \mathbb{z}_\text{blue}$ where the isomorphism swaps red and blue.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you very much for the answer and comments!